# Laravel 5.2 MethodNotAllowedHttpException cant post data

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5

i cant seem to post data in /cars/{id?}/modify

**error:**

```
in RouteCollection.php line 219 at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 206
at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 158
```

**routes:**

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@home');
Route::get('/about', 'PagesController@about');
Route::get('/contact', 'PagesController@contact');
Route::get('/cars', 'CarsController@index');

Route::get('/cars/{id?}/edit', 'CarsController@edit');
Route::post('/cars/{id?}/modify', 'CarsController@update');

Route::get('/cars/add', 'CarsController@add');
Route::post('/cars/add', 'CarsController@store');

Route::get('/cars/{id?}/delete','CarsController@destroy');
```

**html:**

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="/cars/{{ $car->id }}/modify">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}">
        <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="UPDATE">
        <input type="text" id="color_id" name="color_id" value="{!! $car->color_id !!}">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Edit Car Information</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Car Name</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <input type="text" value="{{ $car->name }}" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Car Name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Car Color</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                        <label id="opt1" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <input type="radio" name="color" id="option1" autocomplete="off"> Red
                        </label>
                        <label id="opt2" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <input type="radio" name="color" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Blue
                        </label>
                        <label id="opt3"  class="btn btn-primary">
                            <input type="radio" name="color" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Yellow
                        </label>
                        <label id="opt4" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <input type="radio" name="color" id="option4" autocomplete="off"> Green
                        </label>
                        <label id="opt5" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <input type="radio" name="color" id="option5" autocomplete="off"> Black
                        </label>
                        <label id="opt6" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <input type="radio" name="color" id="option6" autocomplete="off"> White
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <button class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: Remove this `<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="UPDATE">` post is different from update..

Comment: use `patch` instead of `update`

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as an update method/route in laravel. For edits you should use `PUT`.

---

You can fix your problem by changing two things:

Your routing method

```
Route::post('/cars/{id?}/modify', 'CarsController@update');
```

to

```
Route::put('/cars/{id?}/modify', 'CarsController@update');
```

And in your form

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="UPDATE">
```

to

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove this line

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="UPDATE">
```

Or make the route like below

```
Route::update('/cars/{id?}/modify', 'CarsController@update');
```